# Does a voice activated conversation with an AI constitute as natural speech?

Tags: spoken-language, constructed-language, speech-recognition, natural-languages, natural-language-understanding

Since AI bots fulfil all the requirements of speech, but don't fulfil the criteria of 'natural speech' production since it wasn't done impromptu and wasn't developed naturally, do you guys think that a conversation with a chatbot linguistically constitute as a natural conversation? Where would you draw the line?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the call for opinions, there is a specific term for such kind of speech: It is *elicitated speech*. You have this in many forms, including the use of scripts in experiments, visual stimuli, or interaction with speech bots. It typically occurs in linguistic experiments where the stimuli create a comparable environment for all tested speakers.